# executing c++ console application on raspberry pi

Tags: c++, visual-studio, raspberry-pi, console-application

how to run a VS2015 c++ console application on raspberry pi 2. I installed mono, copied the .exe file and try to run it. But it said "Cannot open assembly abc.exe: File does not contain a valid CIL image."

I am new to this method. I couldn't able to try with VisualGDB as my trail license got expired.

Is this method correct?

Answer (score 0):

As melak47 stated in the comments, `mono` is intended for C#, rather than native C++ executables. You may be interested in `Wine`, which is designed to run these native executables

Link: https://www.winehq.org/

Comment: Thank you so much. I referred to the link, I need to know which package to choose for raspberry pi. I hope Ubuntu 14.04 LTS is not the right package for Raspberry Pi 2.